# Vim LaTeX suite now doubles my double parentheses and braces

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I re installed MikTex and Vim LaTeX suite (for an unrelated reason) and now Vim doubles my double parentheses (or braces, etc.).

Usually if I type `(` and the matching `)`, then I get `()<++>` with my cursor inside the parentheses. After the reinstall if I type `(` and the matching `)` I end up with two pairs of parentheses. That is, I end up with `()()<++>` with my cursor inside the second pair of parentheses.

Also, if I double type the caret `^`, then I get `^^^{}<++>` with my cursor inside the braces instead of `^{}<++>` with my cursor inside the braces.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this. Is there a fix? I'm using the same `_vimrc` file (I'm on Win 8 Pro 64 bit).